# ¿Como puedo alinear algunos componentes de un navbar de bootstrap3 a la izquierda y otros a la derecha?

Tags: html5, css, bootstrap, css3

Partiendo de un `navbar` de *Bootstrap* estándar necesitamos que algunos botones o links estén alineados a la izquierda, otros al centro (por ejemplo: nuestro icono `brand`) y otros a la derecha.

Esto fue lo primero que intenté hacer:

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
  <div class="navbar-header">
    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    </button>    
  </div>
  <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
      <li class="navbar-left"><a href="#">Izquierda 1</a></li>
      <li class="navbar-left"><a href="#">Izquierda 2</a></li>
      <li class="active"><a href="#">Center 1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Center</a></li>
      <li class="navbar-right"><a href="#">Derecha 1</a></li>
      <li class="navbar-right"><a href="#">Derecha 2</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Buscando en la documentación de *Bootstrap 3* no encontré ningún ejemplo o idea de cómo lograrlo. ¿Cómo se podría hacer?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Una solución sin necesidad de que modifiques tu estructura html es usar `.pull-right` si el li va a la derecha y `.pull-left` si va a la izquierda y colocando este script:

```
  .navbar-nav {
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;

  }

  .navbar-nav > li {
      float: none;
      display: inline-block;
    }
```

Que nos permite comenzar con todos los `<li>` centrados y luego los jalamos a la derechera y/o izquierda lo que necesitamos.

El final el HTML quedaría así:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
  <div class="navbar-header">
    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    </button>    
  </div>
  <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
      <li class="pull-left"><a href="#">Izquierda 1</a></li>
      <li class="pull-left"><a href="#">Izquierda 2</a></li>
      <li class="active"><a href="#">Center 1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Center</a></li>
      <li class="pull-right"><a href="#">Derecha 1</a></li>
      <li class="pull-right"><a href="#">Derecha 2</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

[Ejemplo en vivo](https://jsfiddle.net/qbeoc1hj/1/)

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta, me parece mas limpia que la mía.

Comment: @Ala Gracias la tuya también es valida.

Answer (score 0):

Esta es una de las soluciones que encontré:

Lo que podemos hacer para lograr alinear cada boton a nuestro gusto es separarlos en varios `<ul>` con su clase correspondiente de *bootstrap*

En este ejemplo alineamos a la derecha 2 links, centramos el `brand` y dos links más alineados a la derecha.

http://www.bootply.com/SlF4kleQfG

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
  <div class="navbar-header">
    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    </button>    
  </div>
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand</a>
  <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-left">
        <li><a href="#">Izquierda</a></li>
        <li><a href="#about">Izquierda</a></li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
      <li><a href="#about">Derecha</a></li>
      <li><a href="#contact">Derecha</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

CSS:

```
.navbar-brand
{
    position:absolute;
    width:100%;
    left:0;
    text-align:center;
    margin:auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Algo sencillo aunque desprolijo es separar los ul con un div con una rejilla de las que vienen definidas en bootstrap:

```
<ul>
 <li></li>
</ul>
<div class="col-md-5"></div>
<ul>
 <li></li>
</ul>
```

A mí me funcionó perfecto. Saludos.

Answer (score -1):

Existe, si no estoy mal, una clase `pull-left` y `pull-right` para hacer que el componente que posea esa clase flote a la derecha o a la izquierda, además existen mixins para incluir eso en less.

Para mas información puedes verificar la sección Clases de Ayuda, [Flotantes rápidos](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#helper-classes-floats), donde puedes encontrar más información al respecto.

Comment: float-left y float-right no son clases.

Comment: Entonces como se les llama?

Comment: Es una propiedad

Comment: No, me refiero a las clases `pull-right` y `pull-left`, clases auxiliares según veo en Bootstrap, que sirven para poner cualquier elemento en con bloque flotante a izquierda o derecha.

Comment: ahora sí, gracias por tu aporte.