# Ajustar elementos li en un navbar de bootstrap

Tags: bootstrap

Deseo saber como ajustar los elementos en un navbar usando bootstrap ya que sobra un espacio a la derecha al incluir todos los elementos `‹li›` en horizontal de una `‹ul›`,  deseo saber como extenderlos a modo que se centren o se aproveche todo el espacio disponible del navbar y que no quede  espacio al final de los elementos

Comment: Tienes conocimientos en css? Altera los componentes de los li para disminuir padding o margin, bootstrap tiene un componente llamado inline list para listas horizontales. Para que no quede espacio sobrante usa las grillas, se crearon para diseño responsivo. Alguna otra duda o si te sirve la respuesta me avisas y la coloco como respuesta,

Comment: No responde tu pregunta pero podría darte una idea de como seguir si lees [esta pregunta](http://es.stackoverflow.com/q/1250/225) con sus respuestas-

Comment: muchas gracias, existe alguna manera de colocar el ultimo elemento horizontal hasta el final del navbar? ya que siempre me sobra un espacio y no se ve bien. este es mi codigo

Comment: Nuevamente amigo, sabes css o sass? con la propiendad `last-child` junto al elemento que desees puede tomar ese elemento y decir que debe flotar a la derecha y no a la izquierda, con eso es suficiente.